# Find and replace column values with Microsoft SQL?

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a column called `<locations>`, I want to find all matching values (ex: Canada) and replace with a different value (ex: Mexico).

How do I go about that?

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic... you might want to consider re-naming that column  "location" (as its singular) instead. There are plenty of discussions/debates on singular versus plural naming that you can also lookup here on SO. For "fun" lookup singular versus plural SQL Table names.  :)

Comment: Thanks Chris, will look into making that change :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
update yourtable set locations = 'Mexico' where locations = 'Canada';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm something like

```
UPDATE yourTable SET locations = 'Mexico' WHERE locations = 'Canada'
```